# How to display Browser name and version with JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I just need to display the browser name and its version on a `<h:outputText/>` in the user's homepage. Can we achieve this via JSF 2.0?

---

Mojarra 2.0.4 - Primefaces 2.2.1- glassfish v3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are as far as I know no JSF components which does that with a single tag or something. The easiest what you can do is just displaying the raw HTTP `User-Agent` header.

```
<h:outputText value="#{header['user-agent']}" />
```

This is only a large and ugly string which is not always decipherable to everyone.

There are however APIs which can convert a HTTP `User-Agent` header into useable information, such as the exact browser make/version and platform make/version, such as [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php).

Once converted the `User-Agent` header into useable parts with help of such an API, you must be able to display the parts of interest in JSF with help of a managed bean the usual way.

Answer (score 14):

Put this method in your bean:

```
public String getBrowserName() {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String userAgent = externalContext.getRequestHeaderMap().get("User-Agent");

    if(userAgent.contains("MSIE")){ 
        return "Internet Explorer";
    }
    if(userAgent.contains("Firefox")){ 
        return "Firefox";
    }
    if(userAgent.contains("Chrome")){ 
        return "Chrome";
    }
    if(userAgent.contains("Opera")){ 
        return "Opera";
    }
    if(userAgent.contains("Safari")){ 
        return "Safari";
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

And then:

```
<h:outputText value="Browser: #{yourBean.browserName}" />
```

Comment: With Internet Explorer It returns "Unkown", why?

Comment: @LizLamperouge you could print the userAgent variable and add another "if contains" block.

Comment: Thank you @Andrés Canavesi , "you could print the userAgent variable and add another "if contains" block", but with what?